# reduction order method $(2-x)y'''+(2x-3)y''-xy'+y=0$, $y_1=e^x$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$(2-x)y'''+(2x-3)y''-xy'+y=0$, $x<2$ being $y_1=e^x$ a solution for the homogeneous equation.
making $y=ue^x$
i came to $u''+u'''=0$
making $u''=w$
,  $w'+w=0$

this way $w=e^{-x}*c_1$ and $y=c_1+c_2xe^x+c_3e^x$.

However the right solution is $y=c_1x+c_2xe^x+c_3e^x$.

Where have i made the mistake?

Thanks

Comment: when you subs $y = ue^x$ you should be getting a non homogeneous equations like in the other problem you had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in the equation for $u$ - you should be getting:
$$(x-2) u'''(x)+(x-3) u''(x)+x^2=0$$
Thus your ansatz of $y=ue^x$ is probably not the way to proceed. It looks like there is some mistake in the original question - as written here, it does not have the solution you stated.

Answer (score 0):

Solve $(2-x)y'''+(2x-3)y''-xy'+y=0,\quad y_1=e^x$.

After substitution $y=u(x)e^x$ we get
$$(x-2) u'''(x)+(x-3) u''(x)=0.$$
Solve this ODE:
$$u''(x)=c_1(x-2)e^{-x},$$
$$u'(x)=c_1\int(x-2)e^{-x}dx+c_2=c_1(1-x)e^{-x}+c_2,$$
$$u(x)=c_1\int(1-x)e^{-x}dx+c_2x+c_3=c_1xe^{-x}+c_2x+c_3$$
Answer:
$$y=u(x)e^x=(c_1xe^{-x}+c_2x+c_3)e^x=c_1x+c_2xe^x+c_3e^x$$